# Как отпустить длл, чтобы её можно было заменить?(Assembly,Methodinfo,invoke)

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как не держать dll, после использования следующей конструкции:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(dll);
Type t = a.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "MainDllClass");
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("WorkTimer");
mi.Invoke(null, arguments);
```

Вызывается метод WorkTimer из класса MainDllClass файла dll.
Почему-то после отработки, он продолжает использоваться и не дает перезаписать файл dll

хм кажется получается вот так:

```
  AppDomain dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("some");     
  AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
  assemblyName.CodeBase = pathToAssembly;
  Assembly a = dom.Load(assemblyName);
  Type t = a.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "MainDllClass");
  MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("WorkTimer");
  mi.Invoke(null, arguments);
  AppDomain.Unload(dom);
```

Буду тестировать, потом отпишусь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дело в том, что методы `Assembly.Load()`, `Assembly.LoadFrom()`, `Assembly.LoadFile()` загружают сборку в текущий домен приложения на постоянной основе. Эта загрузка блокирует файлы сборок. Единственный способ выгрузить сборку - выгрузка целого домена приложения.
Существует прием, позволяющий избежать блокирования сборок, который называется *теневым копированием*: [MSDN. Теневое копирование сборок](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms404279.aspx)

---

Если выгрузка библиотеки вам не требуется, а требуется лишь чтобы библиотеку можно выло безболезненно удалить/заменить при работающем экземпляре приложения (например, обновление ASP.NET приложения), то можно использовать перегруженную версию `Assembly.Load()` принимающую "образ" библиотеки в виде массива байтов, например:

Библиотека:

```
namespace TestLib
{
    public class Summator
    {
        public int Sum(int x, int y) => x + y;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var raw = File.ReadAllBytes(@"Путь\До\Файла\TestLib.dll");
    var assembly = Assembly.Load(raw);
    Type type = assembly.GetTypes().First(x => x.Name == "Summator");
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    MethodInfo mInfo = type.GetMethod("Sum");
    var res = (int)mInfo.Invoke(instance, new object[] { 10, 15 });
    Console.WriteLine(res);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Похоже, что так и есть. Спасибо за ответ, пока подержу в открытом виде. Возможно есть вариант создать какой-то костыль, вроде  временного домена приложения в него загрузить, использовать и выгрузить весь домен функцией AppDomain.Unload, но англоязычный стак придерживается той же версии что и ваша.

Comment: Андрей, я дополнил ответ костылем о котором подумал исходя из вашего ответа, как думаете, такое имеет место быть?

Comment: @xSx, протестируете - посмотрим )

Comment: Странно, но работает :)

Comment: @xSx, дополнил ответ

Comment: ради интереса попробовал так. К великому удивлению byte[] raw = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + dll);
                Assembly a = dom.Load(raw); //Держит файл. Хотя на вход дали массив байт

Comment: @xSx, а файл не был заблокирован до этого? Я когда писал ответ - проверял работоспособность, получалось удалить файл после его загрузки без проблем

Comment: Оопс. Это мои наброски с domainom держали. Если без dom(который мой домайн), то все хорошо

Comment: AppDomain dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain(dll);  
                byte[] raw = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + dll);
                Assembly a = dom.Load(raw);
                AppDomain.Unload(dom); Такая конструкция держит файл...

Comment: @xSx, а если подождать некоторое время? Скорее всего файл не мгновенно будет отпущен

Comment: Прилично жду. Но я вот не пойму, почему вообще он до файла стучит, если мы копию в байтах создали?

Comment: @xSx, только смысла от такой загрузки нету, вы загружаете сборку в домен, а потом домен выгружаете, вы ведь не сможете воспользоваться функционалом этой сборки

Comment: Я весь функционал выпилил, когда искал где он держит. Так то перед unload делается основная работа. Временно сделал через Assembly.load по вашему примеру, после чего вызвал gc, надеюсь почистит переменную raw, а то столько дллок в памяти держать не хорошо.

Comment: @xSx, кстати, почему вы передаете в `CreateDomain()` имя файла? Там параметр - просто [имя домена](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/47e8e141(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: это просто string, не путь

Comment: GC не справляется, память растет на каждый Assembly.load :( Хоть и килобайты, но всё ровно обидно.