# Выгрузка Assembly из приложения

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

Загружаю dll таким кодом:

```
var dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("some");
var assem = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes("Dlib.dll"));

var types = assem.GetTypes();
foreach (var type in types) Logger.Log(type.Name);
AppDomain.Unload(dom);
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

После выгрузки домена сборку можно получить, сняв дамп с процесса.

Возможно ли ее полностью выгрузить?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/676714/218063